# Can't unwrap Optional in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Run-time error  `Can't unwrap Optional.None` on this line   `let tfHppleElement = element.firstChild as TFHppleElement`

```
func fetchDataToParse() {

    let urlToParse = NSURL.URLWithString("http://www.test.com/gotests")
    var err: NSError?
    let htmlData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(urlToParse, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)
        if (err) {
        NSLog("Error NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL, description: \(err.description)")
        return
        }
    let dataParser = TFHpple(HTMLData: htmlData)
    let xpathQueryString = "//div[@class='content-wrapper']/ul/li/a"
    let elements: Array = dataParser.searchWithXPathQuery(xpathQueryString)
        if elements.count == 0 {
        NSLog("No elemnts.count==0 in array  while searchWithXPathQuery ")
        return
        }

    var hrefValue:String?
    var titleValue:String?

        for element : AnyObject in elements{

            let tfHppleElement = element.firstChild as TFHppleElement
            titleValue = tfHppleElement.content

            if (titleValue){
                NSLog("\(titleValue)")
            }

            hrefValue = element.objectForKey("href")
            if (hrefValue){
             NSLog("\(hrefValue)")
             }



        }


}
```

Comment: It's because the values is nil so there is nothing to unwrap. You can get around this by doing `if let tfHppleElement = element.firstChild as TFHppleElement {` and putting your code that depends on the value of `tfHppleElement` within the if block.

Comment: Thanks, but I get compile-time error: Bound value in a conditional binding must be an Optional type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element.firstChild may be nil so you should unwrap it in an if statement

```
if let tfHppleElement = element.firstChild? as? TFHppleElement
{
        titleValue = tfHppleElement.content

        if (titleValue){
            NSLog("\(titleValue)")
        }

        hrefValue = element.objectForKey("href")
        if (hrefValue){
         NSLog("\(hrefValue)")
         }
}
```

that way the code will only access tfHppleElement if it does exist and can be cast to a TFHppleElement

Comment: Thanks, but I get compile-time error: Bound value in a conditional binding must be an Optional type.

Comment: hm try as? TFHppleElement maybe

Comment: what about `as TFHppleElement?` ?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. No compile-time error, but I  get the same run-time error - Can't unwrap Optional.None, on the line -  if let tfHppleElement = element.firstChild as TFHppleElement?{

Comment: hm `element.firstChild?` ? sorry, I seem to be a bit lost here myself

Comment: It seems that `if let tfHppleElement = element.firstChild? as? TFHppleElement{ ` is correct, but I really don`t understand what a hell is happening in this code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: First it checks if element.firstChild is not nil and if it is not then it tries to cast it as a TFHppleElement. if both of those are successful it executes the code in the if